# SQL DATETIME Math

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do the following:

- Format `GetDate()` to display only the minutes
- Format a `varchar` column to display only the minutes
- Subtract the current time `HH:MM:SS` from `GetDate()` and the `VarChar` column

This is what I have

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108) - substring(convert(varchar(20), ColumnName, 9), 13, 5)
```

but I am getting this error and need some help please:

> *Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator.*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is datepart(mi).

To get the minutes for getdate():

```
select datepart(mi, getdate())
```

To subtract a number of minutes from a datetime:

```
select dateadd(mi, - <minutes>, <datevalue>)
```

To remove the time from getdate(), just cast to date (in more recent versions of SQL Server):

```
select cast(getdate() as date)
```

To get the difference in minutes, use datediff:

```
select datediff(mi, <datestart>, <dateend>)
```

What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to take the following time [2012-08-14 10:12:02.690] that is a varchar in a sql column and subtract the current time from that to get the difference by only displaying the difference in minutes...but now I see that if the minutes is greater than 60 it will also need to display the hours as well....is there anyway just to calulate the difference in total minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
declare @str varchar(30)
set @str = '2012-08-14 10:12:02.690'

select datediff(minute, cast(@str as datetime), getdate())
```

Results when `getdate() = '2012-08-14 11:21:10.250'` is total minutes even over 60:

```
69
```